# Loading a JavaScript script dynamically in a Vue.js app

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

How can I load a JavaScript script dynamically in a Vue.js app?

Here's a naive solution:

```html
    <script async v-bind:src="srcUrl"></script>
    <!--<script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=007968012720720263530:10z7awj2l37"></script>-->
```

But the first line doesn't load the script (it does not event add the `script` element to HTML).

The second line works. The second line is identical, just the app variable is replaced with plain text (`srcUrl => https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=007968012720720263530:10z7awj2l37`).

Where's my mistake?

The full demo for reference (it is supposed to load a Google Custom Search Engine on a blank page):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="load-script">
    <div>{{ srcUrl }}</div>
    <div class="gcse-searchbox"></div>
    <div class="gcse-searchresults"></div>
    <script async v-bind:src="srcUrl"></script>
    <!--<script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=007968012720720263530:10z7awj2l37"></script>-->
</div>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#load-script',
        data: {
            srcUrl: "https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=007968012720720263530:10z7awj2l37"
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I found related questions but they don't seem to describe this situation exactly:

- [Why is the vue <template> invalid with v-bind:src?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58386043/why-is-the-vue-template-invalid-with-v-bindsrc)
- [JavaScript load script dynamically inside a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884955/javascript-load-script-dynamically-inside-a-div)
- [How to solve Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand ? Vue.JS 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211760/how-to-solve-interpolation-inside-attributes-has-been-removed-use-v-bind-or-the)
- [How to use img src in vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45880956/how-to-use-img-src-in-vue-js)

Comment: Have you tried my answer below?

Comment: @terrymorse I did, Terry. Let's wait a bit if anyone would suggest a native Vue.js solution with binding. When the script depends on user actions, appending and removing it dynamically is something Vue.js might take care of.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a `<script>` element dynamically to the DOM at any time.

If you're using Vue, you can use its `mounted` property to add a script to the *load-script* div when the page is loaded:

```js
Vue({
  mounted: function () {
    let divScripts = document.getElementById('load-script');
    let newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=007968012720720263530:10z7awj2l37';
    divScripts.appendChild(newScript);
  }
});
```

### Alternate Method — Use LoadScript

As an alternative to adding a function to the `mounted` Vue property, there is a simple Vue plug-in named [LoadScript](https://github.com/tserkov/vue-plugin-load-script) that loads and unloads scripts.

```js
import LoadScript from 'vue-plugin-load-script';
Vue.use(LoadScript);
```

To load a script:

```js
Vue.loadScript('https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=007968012720720263530:10z7awj2l37')
  .then(() => {
    // do something after script loads
  })
  .catch(() => {
    // do something if load fails
  });
```

To unload a script:

```js
Vue.unloadScript('https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=007968012720720263530:10z7awj2l37')
  .then(() => {
    // do something after script unloads
  })
  .catch(() => {
    // do something if unload fails
  });
```